# PyTorch batch Size suddenly reduced after n epochs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a pytorch nn model running on win 10 cpu. 
batch size is 42
After 67 iterations, a strange thing happens: batch size is suddenly reduced to 28, and I get

```
RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (1, 28, 256), got (1, 42, 256)
```

Comment: You mention batch size is 42. But your error says expected size (1, 28, 256) but got (1, 42, 256). That clearly means what you are giving is of size (1, 42, 256), but what is required is (1, 28, 256). Better to check how your model is defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible the number of training examples in the dataset is not divisible by 42? Could it be that the reminder is 28?

If your model cannot handle online change of batch size, you should consider setting `drop_last=True` in your [`torch.utils.data.DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader), thus only full batches will be processed during training.

Comment: Indeed: trainLoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainSet, shuffle=True, batch_size=batchSize,*drop_last=True*) solves the issue. thanks!